# Change the value of input attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I need to change the hardcoded url in the value property of input attribute dynamically based on a dropdown selected.

Following is the code I tried but not working. I am new to Javascript. Please help

```js
var returnValue = checkDropDown();
var myValue = returnValue === "DropDown1" ? "http://url1/..." : "http://url2..";
var input = document.getElementById('URLField');
input.value = myValue;

function checkDropDown() {
  const platForm = $('#platform-select').val();

  console.log("platform select"+platForm);
  return platForm;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <label for="platform">Choose from dropdown :</label>
      <select name="platform" id="platform-select" onchange="togglePlatformOptions()">
       <option value="DropDown1" >foo</option>
       <option value="DropDown2" selected>bar</option>
      </select> 

  <input type="text" id="URLField" value="myValue"/>

</body>
```

Comment: where is ```checkDropDown()``` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already have a function defined on change event on dropdown(called togglePlatformOptions) you can just use it.
Just add to this function your functionality.
Like below

```
function togglePlatformOptions(){
   //you old code if it exists already
   var returnValue = document.getElementById('platform-select').value;
   var myValue = returnValue === "DropDown1" ? "http://url1/..." : "http://url2..";
   var input = document.getElementById('URLField');
   input.value = myValue;
}
```

UPDATE: Seems you have a function checkDropDown, then add everything you have inside

```
function togglePlatformOptions(){
  var returnValue = checkDropDown();
  var myValue = returnValue === "DropDown1" ? "http://url1/..." : "http://url2..";
  var input = document.getElementById('URLField');
  input.value = myValue;
}
```

UPDATE #2: To have it on initialization just call it

```
function togglePlatformOptions(){
  var returnValue = checkDropDown();
  var myValue = returnValue === "DropDown1" ? "http://url1/..." : "http://url2..";
  var input = document.getElementById('URLField');
  input.value = myValue;
}
// below call added
togglePlatformOptions();
```

Comment: I tried this but initially the value is displayed as "myvalue".And then when i toggle dropdown it works fine but initially at the page load it is displayed as myValue

Comment: yes, it's expected because onchange event is fired once you change your option in dropdown.
to get it works on initialization just add function call after function function togglePlatformOptions(){... }declaration togglePlatformOptions();

Comment: how can i have a default url2 selected on pageload??

Comment: could you please show the code snippet how to add function call after function